# IPC and its application aream

Tags: operating-system, ipc

I have learned about basics of IPC's(pipe,socket,message queue,shared memory) and done
small basic programs using these above IPC.

My question is: i want to know application areas of IPC. for example data coming from
server to client using FTP. here multiple process need to copy and share this data. so for this application which IPC shall i use?

like wise can you people list out these kind real time example and corresponding IPC's
which is most suitable for that kind of application?

so this kind of example and corresponding IPC helps me to identify correct IPC and its broaden my knowledge.

Comment: See [MSDN: Transports in Windows Communication Foundation → Choosing a Transport](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733769(v=vs.110).aspx) for an example of IPC decision making. [Inter-process communication (IPC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication) covers almost anything that computer programs do. So this question is very broad and open-ended and does not satisfy site's [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) rules

Comment: Is your question about best practice of different IPC? Please refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4849845/usage-of-different-ipc-mechanism